# Improving on loop-recur

Tags: clojure

I wrote a function that tries to get a y/n (yes/no) answer from a user interactively. It tests if the answer is valid and if not, solicits the user again:

```
(defn get-valid-answer [question]
   (println  question)
   (loop []
     (let [ans (.trim (read-line))]
        (if (#{"y" "n"} ans)
            ans
            (do (println "Please answer \"y\"[yes] or \"n\"[no] only!")
                (recur) )))))
```

The above version with loop-recur does the job but I have nagging feeling that there must be a better (more functional) way to do this. I would prefer to have the read-line call made just once.  Could anyone suggest an alternative version not using loop-recur in this scenario but possibly using some (Clojure builtin) macro instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of a small child asking the same question endlessly until it gets a satisfactory reply, then do the same thing in code.  That is to say, take the first valid answer from an endless stream of questions.

Untested, but this should do the trick.

```
(defn ask []
  (println "Please answer \"y\"[yes] or \"n\"[no]:")
  (.trim (read-line)))

(defn get-valid-answer [question]
  (println question)
  (->> (repeatedly ask)
       (filter #{"y" "n"})
       (first)))
```

You could also define 'ask' in a `let` binding, if two functions bothers you.

Comment: That is neat. I have tested that it works. But I have a question about your approach: I see that 'repeatedly' makes lazy calls to ask and I thought that lazy functions evaluate chunks of 32 at a time, so that there may be 32 invocations to ask. By my test, I can see that doesn't happen. Does the 'first' tell Clojure to override the 32 (thunk-size) and make only one invocation to ask?

Comment: If you read the source for LazySeq (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java), you can see for yourself that items are evaluated one at a time.  I've seen the post you're referring to, but I'm not sure when that was true, if ever.

Comment: Only some lazy sequences are chunked. `repeatedly` is not one, but for example `map` and `range` are.

Comment: There's more to it. I found a chunked-seq? function which returns true for the lazy-seqs returned by range and map ONLY when they are wrapped in a seq but with repeatedly you always get false: http://pastie.org/4333243